# How do I publish artifacts with checksums (MD5, SHA1)?

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

I would like `sbt publish` to publish my JARs with some checksum however I can't seem to be able to achieve that.

The documentation says that checksums are enabled by default and I can confirm that checksums returns me md5 and sha1 in sbt. I can also see the generated checksums if I do `sbt publishLocal`. However there are no checksums when I do `sbt publish` on our CI server when publishing JARs to our company Artifactory server.

What am I missing?

More info:

- sbt 1.4.6
- `publishMavenStyle := true`
- `publishTo := <internal Artifactory>`
- I would say it's specific to my company's Artifactory because `publishLocal` works well.
- `publish / checksums` returns the same thing as just checksums which is a list of md5 and sha1 values (the only two values that are supported by sbt as far as I could find).
- I've tried to turn off Coursier (just a hunch) and it behaved the same.

I've tried the debug log level and this is what is at the end of the build:

```
  [debug] Done packaging.
20:27:44
  [debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://<artifactory>/artifactory/maven-local/com/avast/ip-info_2.13/2.8.28/ip-info_2.13-2.8.28.pom
20:27:44
  [info]   published ip-info_2.13 to https://<artifactory>/artifactory/maven-local/com/avast/ip-info_2.13/2.8.28/ip-info_2.13-2.8.28.pom
20:27:44
  [debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://<artifactory>/artifactory/maven-local/com/avast/ip-info_2.13/2.8.28/ip-info_2.13-2.8.28.jar
20:27:44
  [info]   published ip-info_2.13 to https://<artifactory>/artifactory/maven-local/com/avast/ip-info_2.13/2.8.28/ip-info_2.13-2.8.28.jar
20:27:44
  [debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://<artifactory>/artifactory/maven-local/com/avast/ip-info_2.13/2.8.28/ip-info_2.13-2.8.28-sources.jar
20:27:44
  [info]   published ip-info_2.13 to https://<artifactory>/artifactory/maven-local/com/avast/ip-info_2.13/2.8.28/ip-info_2.13-2.8.28-sources.jar
20:27:44
  [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 28, 2021, 7:27:44 PM
```

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? What about if you raise the log level to `debug`? Are you sure that `publish / checksums` is true? (Sometimes people are using some company sbt plugin that sets settings they aren't aware of.) You'll have a better chance of getting help with this if you include details of the investigations and experiments you've already performed yourself to try to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Is the problem unique to your company's Artifactory, or does it happen in any kind of publishing? Is the problem unique to a particular repo, or does it reproducible in a fresh repo with minimal config?

Comment: We're using JFrog Artifactory version 6.23.7. I can't really create fresh repos to test anything out but there are other projects in the same Maven repo which do have the checksums - but those are built using Gradle.

Comment: Yes, I do use company sbt plugins that setup certain things for me but I am the creator of them so I kind of know what they are doing and there isn't anything special that should prevent the checksums from being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is JFrog, and not SBT.

For example, we can see that [play-json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json) has no checksums mentions in its [`build.sbt`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/build.sbt), nor [anywhere else in their repository](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/search?q=checksums). Yet, looking at their [published artifacts at maven](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.13/2.9.2/), I see there both sha-1, and md5 artifacts.

When browsing a bit, I found this:

[How to show the checksum files when browsing artifacts from the direct URL?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-show-the-checksum-files-when-browsing-artifacts-from-the-direct-url/)

Which makes me to think that JFrog hides it. The resolution there is:

> Simply set a property in the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties file.
>
> 1. Add the following property to the artifactory.system.properties file and save lit:
>    artifactory.ui.hideChecksums=false
> 2. Restart Artifactory for the change to take effect:

I must admit I didn't try it, but it is probably a lead.